# pandas - Adding rows of summed column data to a dataframe based on values in multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating multi-index dataframes with about 200 rows and variable number of columns, they look something like this:

```
data = [{'measure':'value1','name':'A','type':'x','t1':3,'t2':5},
        {'measure':'value1','name':'B','type':'y','t1':30,'t2':33},
        {'measure':'value1','name':'C','type':'y','t1':30,'t2':33},
        {'measure':'value2','name':'A','type':'x','t1':25,'t2':11}, 
        {'measure':'value2','name':'B','type':'y','t1':4,'t2':4},
        {'measure':'power','name':'A','type':'x','t1':'off','t2':'off'}, 
        {'measure':'power','name':'B','type':'y','t1':'on','t2':'off'}
        {'measure':'power','name':'C','type':'y','t1':'off','t2':'nan'}
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.set_index(['measure','name','type'])
```

```
                    t1   t2
measure name type          
value1  A    x       3    5
        B    y      30   33
        C    y      30   33
value2  A    x      25   11
        B    y       4    4
power   A    x     off  off
        B    y      on  off
        C    y     off  nan
```

I want to test certain things without having to go through the whole dataframe in excel. Since I am printing the dataframes to CSV I'd like to have those test results appended as a new row at the bottom.

I can't figure out how to perform functions, let's say sum two non-consecutive rows, based on the status of a third row. I've tried `.loc` and `.groupby` but so far no success.

As an example I'd like to have an outcome as shown below: add rows that display the sum per `'type'`  of all value1 and value2 if any `'name'` of that type has `power == 'on'`

```
                    t1   t2
measure name type          
value1  A    x       3    5
        B    y      30   33
        C    y      30   33
value2  A    x      25   11
        B    y       4    4
power   A    x     off  off
        B    y      on  off
SUM     nan  x     nan  nan  # name doesn't have to be 'nan'; just not 'A' or 'B'
        nan  y      34  nan
```

Comment: Hi there, just wanted to point out that in row 5 of your data you have some string types that I think should be int types `'t1':'4','t2':'4'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
#calculation
#boolean matrix to map where the value should be taken
power_bool = df.loc["power"]=="on"

#calculation of column-wise sum depending on name property
sum_df = df.loc[["value1","value2"]].groupby(["name"]).sum()

#addition of rows
#inconvenient for loop, because "values1" and "power" dont have the same shape
for row in df.loc["power"].itertuples():
    #combine calculated sum and "power"-filter row-wise
    sum_test = sum_df.loc[[row.Index[0]]].where(power_bool.loc[row.Index[0]].values)
    df.loc["SUM",row.Index[0]+"sum", row.Index[1]] = sum_test.values[0]
    
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                    t1   t2
measure name type          
value1  A    x       3    5
        B    y      30   33
        C    y      30   33
value2  A    x      25   11
        B    y       4    4
power   A    x     off  off
        B    y      on  off
SUM     Asum x     NaN  NaN
        Bsum y      34  NaN
```

Comment: thanks! A lot of comments around here discourage use of for loops on dataframes, so I hadn't looked into that yet. What does 'shape' mean? if it's unequal amount of rows per index group then yes, this would happen all the time in the actual data as well.

Comment: what's deviating here from the question is that this sums over `"name"`, not `"type"`. If I change the `.groupby` from `" name"` to `"type"` in your `sum_df` definition, I get the sum of B and C, even though C has "off" status. Summing over `"name"` would require another function to then get the sum per `"type"`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean with "shape". In my opinion this is the main contributor to why this turns out to be so complex. However, I have to admit that I am no expert either, there might very well be a much cleaner way that I cant think of. For your second comment: Is there any possibility that a row with `name C` is added to the power subset? I think that would make it easier and you wrote that it is `off`, so the value seems to be known.

Comment: In the real data set there are some two dozen `"name"` values so I decided to stop somewhere. I think I can make it so that they all have a row in the `power` subset, but they may not have a value there, except when it's `"on"` (i.e. `nan` would equate to `"off"`) but that's workable. I will change the original entry to reflect this